# If target cell time (formatted as hh:mm:ss) is within a range, active cell displays text

Tags: excel, excel-formula, conditional-formatting

Active cell is B2. Reference cell is A2, formatted as hh:mm:ss

B2 will display specific text depending on what time is manually inputted in A2. Specifically:

If manually inputted text in B2 is between 12:07:00 - 12:06:00, A1 will display text "Z1".
If manually inputted text in B2 is between 12:05:59 - 12:05:30, A1 will display text "Z2".
If manually inputted text in B2 is between 12:05:29 - 12:05:00, A1 will display text "Z3". etc.

Preference is for an IF function, and not a VLOOKUP. Have tried with a VLOOKUP but I'm obviously doing something wrong:

Undesired result 1 for `VLOOKUP` attempt:
[image: Undesired result 1 for Vlookup attempt]

Undesired result 2 for `VLOOKUP` attempt:
[image: Undesired result 2 for Vlookup attempt]

Thank you!

Comment: though I wouldn't mind creating a separate reference table either to satisfy a vlookup either... then why not just do that?

Comment: Why would you want a nested if with "hard coded" values in lieu of a reference table and a simple VLOOKUP?

Comment: @BigBen apologies for not clarifying the statement.  I understand the VLOOKUP conceptually, but not how to actually format it and craft the formula. 

But, the preference is for a nested IF with "hard coded" values. I'm still getting my feet wet with all the possible solutions to my concern, inefficient, or not. 

As mentioned, both solutions would be much appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: @ScottCraner, as mentioned, I just want to familiarize myself with possible solutions, inefficient, simplified, and/or everything in between.

Comment: We're telling you that a VLOOKUP is probably the best way to go here... have you tried it yet? Sounds like you know what possible solutions are, so maybe try them.

Comment: @BigBen, yes I understand. Like I said, I get it conceptually but not how to actually craft the formula. As for trying it, I have, and I'm just getting errors. I'm obviously getting the formula wrong, which is why I'm asking for solutions.

Comment: Can you [edit] your question with how you're trying the formula? So that your question is a [reprex].

Comment: @BigBen , I added screenshots of the undesired results on my attempt with vlookup in the body of my question. Hope I did that right.

Comment: Yes, much appreciated. Your lookup list needs sorted from lowest to highest I think. Or you can use INDEX/MATCH.

Comment: @BigBen, sorry you'll have to help me out. Not familiar with INDEX/MATCH. As for arranging from lowest to highest, I tried it out, it's still returning undesired results.

Answer (score 0):

As a start, I can give you following example, which returns "AAA" in case the time is larger than 12h05.00, and "BBB" in other case:

```
=IF(B1>=TIME(12;5;0);"AAA";"BBB")
```

Obviously, you'll need to be able to combine conditions, like:

```
=AND(B1>=TIME(12;5;0);B1<=TIME(12;6;0))
```

(which you'll need to embed in your formula)

From here, you have a good start.
In case you still have issues, you can comment this answer.

Comment: Thanks for this. I understand how to execute for a true false, however the resulting text displayed, number more than 2. I need it to display either, Z1, Z2, Z3, all the way to Z7 depending on the range.

Answer (score 0):

I know you wanted an if statement however I fixed your vlookup problem for this. You would list the times in ascending order and use the formula =vlookup(a2,$E:$F,2,True). Your column d values are not useful here. This will look up the closest match for A2 that doesn't pass the amount in E.
[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hCCXA.png)